# Saldo por data no mysql

Tags: php, mysql, data

eu tenho uma tabela pedidos e gostaria de retornar a seguinte situação.
selecionar todos os pedido de um idCliente do mês corrente somando os valores dos mesmos. tipo `select * from pedidos where idCliente = id and dataPedido`(o mes da pesquisa tipo 10/2018) `sum(valortotalPedido)` não estou conseguindo porque o campo data no mysql esta da seguinte forma 2018-10-01 22:02:01 ou seja formato padrão. não sei se fui claro mas agradeço quem puder ajudar

Comment: O campo do MySQL está perfeito. As coisas funcionam exatamente nesse formato, o que falta é você usar a lógica adequada na comparação (que eventualmente podem surgir nas respostas).

Answer (score 2):

Para retornar a soma dos valores por cliente:

```
$mes = date('m');
$ano = date('Y');

SELECT sum(valortotalPedido) FROM pedidos
WHERE idCliente = $id and Month(dataPedido) = $mes and Year(dataPedido) = $ano
```

Como a consulta utiliza a função de agregação `sum`, não será possível retornar a lista de pedidos de forma consistente, já que o campo "valortotalPedido" estará agrupado.

Answer (score 1):

Receba a data que você usa Dia/Mes/Ano converta para Ano/Mes/Dia, pegue o ano e o mês que a data fornece e coloque na query.

```
// Data recebida Dia/Mês/Ano
$data       = '01-11-2018 22:02:01';
// Converta a data para Ano/Mes/Dia
$data       = date('Y-m-d G:i:s', strtotime($data));
// Pegue o Mês da data
$mes        = date('m', strtotime($data));
// Pegue o Ano da data
$ano        = date('Y', strtotime($data));
$query  = "SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE MONTH(data) = ':MES' AND YEAR(data) = ':ANO'";
```

**Modificar o formato da data:**

```
date('Y-m-d G:i:s', strtotime('01-10-2018 22:02:01'));
```

**Retorno:**

```
2018-10-01 22:02:01
```

**Mais informações:**
[date](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php) [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: Obrigado amigo, baseado em sua resposta consegui o que queria da seguinte forma 
  $mes = date('m');
  $ano = date('Y');
  $query = "SELECT SUM(valortotalPedido) AS total FROM $this->pedidos WHERE MONTH(dataPedido) = :data AND YEAR(dataPedido) = :ano AND idCliente = :id";

Comment: De nada, @LucianodePaula