# Convertendo Data PHP para o formato pt_br

Tags: php, data

Como eu consigo converter a data de `2019-02-22` para o formato brasileiro `22/02/2019`?

```
$data_atual = date('d-m-Y H:i:s');

date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');    
$data_ult_aces = $row_ult_aces['data_acesso'];
$ob_data_atual = new DateTime($data_atual);
$ob_data_ult_aces = new DateTime($data_ult_aces);
```

Tentei também usar o `date_format('d/m/y');` não funcionou.

Comment: Talvez ajude-o: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/348155/99718 **e** https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/109985/99718 **e** https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/338494/99718 **e** https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/358583/99718

Comment: nao precisa colocar o (Resolvido) no titulo, basta aceitar a resposta que resolveu seu problema e ta tudo certo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade e bem simples, so usar o metodo [format()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.format.php) da classe [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.datetime.php)

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');    
$data_ult_aces = $row_ult_aces['data_acesso'];
$ob_data_atual = new DateTime($data_atual);
$ob_data_ult_aces = new DateTime($data_ult_aces); 

$data_atual_formatada = $ob_data_atual->format('d/m/Y');
$data_ult_aces_formatada = $ob_data_ult_aces->format('d/m/Y');
```

Answer (score 1):

Para imprimir no formato Brasileiro basta usar o [`date();`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php) com o formato:

```
date('d/m/Y');
```

Aonde d/m/Y são respectivamente Dia Mês e Ano

> No [Link](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php) te as informações dos parâmetros possíveis, que também e usável na query.

Para converter basta usar :

```
$dataAmericana = "2010-03-21";
$dataBr = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($dataAmericana));
```

Já caso queria converter direto da sua query Mysql basta usar o [`date_format()`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp), por exemplo:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT("2017-06-15", "%d/%m/%Y");
```

Nesse exemplo eu teria o retorno **15/06/2017**, em uso de uma consulta bastaria trocar a data estática pela coluna do tipo `date`. Exemplo:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_At, "%d/%m/%Y") from table;
```

Comment: então eu peguei algumas ideias de como mudar dessa biblioteca porem só retorna erro na linha e não formata a data

Comment: @WesleyRoberto Qual erro que ocorre? e não entendi quando fala biblioteca, o date(); é nativo do php.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: data_atual in C:\xampp\htdocs\ultimoacesso\adm\app\adms\listar\list_usuario.php on line 96

Comment: falei blibioteca por conter muitos outras opções, não por ser uma blibioteca tipo js, mais não deu certo retorna esse erro sempre mesmo com as ideias dos amigos abaixo, ta compliado.

Comment: @WesleyRoberto cara esse erro não tem a ver com a função de converter, essa variável `$data_atual` não existe, seu problema está aí. Você tá usando uma variável que não foi definida.

Comment: valeu galera resolvi usando
$data = new DateTime($data_ult_aces);
echo $data->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');

Agora minhha dúvida é como eu consigo inserir os dados no banco no horario atual do Brasil.